# MobiLink: How to propagade schema change for a synch profile to remote databases

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sap, mobilink, sybase-central

Once an application is online with a synchronisation profile it might happen, that the profile needs to be changed. E.g. a new index is introduced, columns are added etc.

Having the synchronisation profile created with Sybase Central, what's the designated way to propagate these changes to remote databases? The only option here seems to be to complete new create a profile or update current one including complete regeneration of remote database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobilink can also pass schemachanges to it's replicated databases.
For this, there exists the [start synchronization schema change statement](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/start-synchronization-schema-change-statement.html)

This looks like this:

```
START SYNCHRONIZATION SCHEMA CHANGE
  FOR TABLES DBA.Sales, DBA.Products
  SET SCRIPT VERSION = 'version_2';
ALTER TABLE DBA.Sales ADD SUBTOTAL NUMERIC (10,2);
ALTER TABLE DBA.Products ALTER QUANTITY BIGINT;
STOP SYNCHRONIZATION SCHEMA CHANGE;
```

Comment: This I have found. But was wondering whether this can be triggered directly via Sybase Central which is considered based upon documentation as single point of configuration.

Comment: I don't think so. Also for SQLRemote you have to make this manually. It is just to dangerous to have done this implicit by Sybase Central

Comment: Hmmm. I was afraid of this answer. Inconsistent as the rest at least. Anyway, upvote is sent out ;)

Comment: At http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108679/30833 I found a way which is might more "Sybase Central" like.